# How to validate a reactive form control that is dependent on another form control?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-forms

Angular Form component class is :

```
export class SpecsFilterFormComponent implements OnInit {

  specFilterForm: FormGroup;
  cameraSizeMin = new FormControl("", [Validators.pattern("\s*|[0-9.]*")]);
  cameraSizeMax = new FormControl("", [Validators.pattern("\s*|[0-9.]*")]);

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {    }

  ngOnInit() {

  this.specFilterForm = this.fb.group({
  cameraSize: this.fb.group(
    {
      cameraSizeMin: this.cameraSizeMin,
      cameraSizeMax: this.cameraSizeMax,
    })
});

this.specFilterForm.valueChanges.debounceTime(500).filter(
  formData => this.specFilterForm.valid)
  .subscribe(
    formData => {
      console.log("do something after validation")
    });
  }
  }
```

I want to add a validation to make sure that cameraSizeMax  >= cameraSizeMin, how to apply this validation in the from control cameraSizeMin and cameraSizeMax.

Comment: can use Validator.compose to include the current validation and the other validation criteria(custom validator).

Answer (score 5):

I have created a custom validator that is applied to the complete formgroup and adds then the error at the form control:

Following sets the cameraSizeMin to invalid.

```
class CustomValidator {
  static validate(abstractForm: FormGroup): {[key: string]: any} => {
    let cameraSizeMin = abstractForm.get("cameraSizeMin");
    let cameraSizeMax = abstractForm.get("cameraSizeMax");

    //validation logic in condition below
    if (true) {
      cameraSizeMin.setErrors({"customValidation": true});
    }
  }
}
```

You register it to the formGroup by:

```
this.specFilterForm = this.fb.group({
  cameraSize: this.fb.group(
    {
      cameraSizeMin: this.cameraSizeMin,
      cameraSizeMax: this.cameraSizeMax,
    }, {validator: CustomValidator.validate}
  )
});
```

Comment: Hi, How to write multple validation like above in one form

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar if you have a new question, please use the Ask Question button to ask a new question.